# Move the mouse() to a given [x, y] co-ordinate then click and input data using Karate framework

Tags: karate, ui-automation

Using Selenium  Java -->

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

 action.moveToElement(webElement, 100, 200).click().perform();

 action.sendKeys("textToWrite");
```

Using Karate -->

From Karate documentation at https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/karate-core/#chaining

Image

[image: 1]

mouse().move(100,200)).click()

but could not find anything  for data input (Similar to sendKeys in selenium ) .

I tried using input (locator,'textToWrite)  but it can not be used as there is x,y coordinates instead of text locator to locate element

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `input('body', 'some text')` after you do the `click()`, it can be the next step.

If that doesn't work - please provide a link to a live example, and we will have to figure out if something needs to be improved.